# Moving variable to next column in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm having the following table in SAS

```
SAS Table: Price
 
    ID Description Price Discount
    20 Hot blue    warm    12.0 
    21 Durable A   15.0     0 
    22 Flexible    13.5     0 
    23 Bendable    and A   12.3
```

I'm planning to move 'warm' and 'and A' from Price column to Description column while '12.0' and '12.3' to Price, what should I do?

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem if the data were delimited correctly in the first place when it was input.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the type of an existing variable, but you can change the name.
Use the INPUT() function to convert strings to numbers.  You can use the ?? modifier to suppress errors generated by strings that do not represent numbers.

```
data want;
  set price(rename=(price=char_price));
  price = input(char_price,??32.)
  if missing(price) then description=catx(' ',description,char_price);
run;
```

Comment: I tried but got this error :
 ERROR: Variable description already exists on file WORK.PRICE.
 ERROR: Invalid DROP, KEEP, or RENAME option on file WORK.PRICE.

Comment: So your input dataset already has a variable named DESCRIPTION.  You will need to use a different name for the character version of PRICE.  Updated code in answer.